# Cassandra database, which python interface?

Tags: python, database, cassandra, thrift

I'm going to write the web portal using Cassandra databases.
Can you advise me which python interface to use? **thrift, lazygal or pycassa**?
Are there any benefits to use more complicated thrift then cleaner pycassa?
What about performace - is the same (all of them are just the layer)?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pycassa if you don't know what to use.

Use lazyboy if you want it to maintain indexes for you.  It's significantly more complex.